# How to create Pandas Series with Decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, decimal

I'm calculating some standard deviations which are giving FloatingPointErrors. I wanted to try converting the data series to Decimal (using https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), to see if this fixes my issue.

I can't seem to make a pandas series of `decimal`.

How can I take a normal `pd.Series` of `float64` and convert to a `pd.Series` of `decimal`, such that I can do:

```
Series.pct_change().ewm(span=35, min_periods=35).std()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from decimal import Decimal

df['col_a'] = df['col_a'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(str(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

would something like this work?

```
def column_round(decimals):
     return partial(Series.round, decimals=decimals)

df.apply(column_round(2))
```

alternatively lets use `np.vectorize` so we can use `decimal.quantize` function to do rounding, this will leave the variable as a decimal instead of `np.float64`

```
npquantize = np.vectorize(decimal.Decimal.quantize)
```

I have been looking into it and this seems to solve the issue with pct_change

```
ts.diff().div(ts.shift(1))
```

Comment: If I've understood correctly, this still uses floating point arithmetic; I want to enforce decimal arithmetic.

Comment: have you considered converting the series into a numpy array and apply np.vectorize prior to applying todecimal?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create the DataFrame directly with Decimal types and operate with the values

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from decimal import *

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DECIMAL_1': [Decimal('2342.2345234'), Decimal('564.5678'), Decimal('76867.8923892')],
    'DECIMAL_2': [Decimal('67867.43534534323'), Decimal('67876.345345'), Decimal('234234.2345345')]
})
df['DECIMAL_3'] = df['DECIMAL_1'] + df['DECIMAL_2']
df.dtypes
```

The drawback could be that the columns `dtype` is going to be `object` and the performance will decrease, I am afraid. Anyway, I think that any operation with the `Decimal` will require more computation than operating with floats.

Maybe the best solution is to have a copy of the DataFrame. One DF with floats and the other one with Decimal. If you need to make fast operations you can use the DF with floats, if you need to compare or assign new values to some cells with some specific precision you can use the DF created with Decimal.

Tell me what you think about my suggestions.

**Note:** I made my example with DataFrame, but a DataFrame is built with Series